# Liquibase-Hibernate: How to generate changelog from Spring-Boot JPA entities?

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm having troubles generating the initial changelog from the JPA Entities of my Spring-Boot project.
My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>eu.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>organization</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>organization</name>
    <description>Project Organization</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--======================================== OAuth2 Resource Server ========================================-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--=============================================== Database ===============================================-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>./src/main/resources/database/liquibase/isolated/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the following is the liquibase.properties file:

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/database/liquibase/isolated/master.xml
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/database/liquibase/isolated/init.xml
url=hibernate:spring:eu.project.organization.domain.isolated?dialect=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateGenericDialect
defaultSchemaName=public
driver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
verbose=true
```

When I run the command

```
mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -X
```

It keeps getting a NullPointerException on the `catalogs` of the DB [[Full log on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hjmQkdv1)]:

```
[DEBUG] com.datical.liquibase.ext.storedlogic.checkconstraint.postgres.PostgresCheckConstraintSnapshotGenerator matches liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGenerator
[DEBUG] com.datical.liquibase.ext.storedlogic.trigger.postgres.PostgresTriggerSnapshotGenerator matches liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGenerator
[DEBUG] Computed checksum for 1586893861875 as 5a982a4378e869d59b22108df3d2b645
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.192 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-14T21:51:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.9:generateChangeLog (default-cli) on project organization: 
[ERROR] Error setting up or running Liquibase:
[ERROR] liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.9:generateChangeLog (default-cli) on project organization: 
Error setting up or running Liquibase:
liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
Error setting up or running Liquibase:
liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:289)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:258)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseGenerateChangeLogMojo.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseGenerateChangeLogMojo.java:122)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:401)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:24)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:287)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:258)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseGenerateChangeLogMojo.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseGenerateChangeLogMojo.java:122)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:401)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.getDatabaseCatalogNames (JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:147)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject (CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:35)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot (JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:66)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot (SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include (DatabaseSnapshot.java:316)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init (DatabaseSnapshot.java:101)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init> (DatabaseSnapshot.java:60)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init> (JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:39)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot (SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:217)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot (SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:190)
    at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot (DiffCommand.java:229)
    at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createDiffResult (DiffCommand.java:151)
    at liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run (GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:60)
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:19)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:287)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:258)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseGenerateChangeLogMojo.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseGenerateChangeLogMojo.java:122)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:401)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Apparently the changelog is being generated correcltly because it shows the computed checksum, but it fails in the end at

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.getDatabaseCatalogNames (JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:147)
```

How can I fix this problem in order to have it generating the changelog based on the JPA entities without having to use a real Database?

**UPDATE**

After adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

the error message changed and now it is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : eu.project.organization.domain.isolated.Employee
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass (AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName (ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init> (AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init> (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:931)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateEjb3Database.buildMetadataFromPath (HibernateEjb3Database.java:58)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.buildMetadata (HibernateDatabase.java:145)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.setConnection (HibernateDatabase.java:85)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findCorrectDatabaseImplementation (DatabaseFactory.java:129)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase (DatabaseFactory.java:149)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject (CommandLineUtils.java:97)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject (CommandLineUtils.java:67)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:349)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working by adding the [Bean Validation API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api) & [Javassist](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist) dependencies to the liquibase plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>./src/main/resources/database/liquibase/isolated/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The `liquibase.properties` file is as follows:

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/database/liquibase/isolated/master.xml
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/database/liquibase/isolated/init.xml
url=hibernate:spring:eu.project.organization.domain.isolated?dialect=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateGenericDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
driver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
```

Now, running the command `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog` correctly generates the initial changelog in the `init.xml` file.